# Performance comparison of two implementations of a primes filter

Tags: performance, list, haskell

I have two programs to find prime numbers (just an exercise, I'm learning Haskell). "primes" is about 10X faster than "primes2", once compiled with ghc (with flag -O). However, in "primes2", I thought it would consider only prime numbers for the divisor test, which should be faster than considering odd numbers in "isPrime", right? What am I missing?

```
isqrt :: Integral a => a -> a  
isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool  
isPrime n = length [i | i <- [1,3..(isqrt n)], mod n i == 0] == 1

primes :: Integral a => a -> [a]  
primes n = [2,3,5,7,11,13] ++ (filter (isPrime) [15,17..n])

primes2 :: Integral a => a -> [a]  
primes2 n = 2 : [i | i <- [3,5..n], all ((/= 0) . mod i) (primes2 (isqrt i))]
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the issue is that there's no sharing going on in `primes2`; every time you call `primes2 (isqrt i)`, you're regenerating the whole list.

Comment: Interesting. No memoization of primes2? (PS: I'm not sure I understand memoization so well, bear with me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that `isPrime` is a simple loop, whereas `primes2` is calling itself recursively — and its recursion pattern looks exponential to me.

Searching through my old source code, I found this code:

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3,5..]

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime x = all (\n -> x `mod` n /= 0) $
            takeWhile (\n -> n * n <= x) primes
```

This tests each possible prime `x` only against the primes below `sqrt(x)`, using the already generated list of primes.  So it probably doesn't test any given prime more than once.

**Memoization in Haskell:**

Memoization in Haskell is generally *explicit*, not *implicit*.  The compiler won't "do the right thing" but it will only do what you tell it to.  When you call `primes2`,

```
*Main> primes2 5
[2,3,5]
*Main> primes2 10
[2,3,5,7]
```

Each time you call the function it calculates all of its results all over again.  It has to.  Why?  Because 1) You didn't make it save its results, and 2) the answer is different each time you call it.

In the sample code I gave above, `primes` is a constant (i.e. it has arity zero) so there's only one copy of it in memory, and its parts only get evaluated once.

If you want memoization, you need to have a value with arity zero somewhere in your code.

Comment: But... I was hoping that the successive values of the set primes2 would be memoized. Also, primes2 (in my limited understanding) was  looping _less_ than isPrime, since there are less primes up to n than odd numbers.

Comment: @hammar: Nitpicking here, but `primes2` is a value as are all functions.  The important distinction is that `primes2` has nonzero arity, which means that in practice, every application will yield a different thunk.  (Huh, looks like hammar deleted the comment...)

Comment: That solution performs really well once compiled. Too bad it doesn't fit on a single line :-)

Comment: No problem! How about: primes2 :: [Integer]
primes2 = 2 : [i | i <- [3,5..], all ((/= 0) . mod i) primes2]. I tried, it doesn't seem to do much, although it compiles fine.

Comment: There is almost always a tradeoff between performance and readability.  In Haskell, the fastest code is usually clever, and the cleverest code is usually slow.

Comment: @Frank: That new definition of `primes2` evaluates to `2 : _|_`, which is not what you want.  That's what you get when you apply `all` to an infinite list.

Comment: More than "clever", I'm just trying to be declarative, as in "The set of primes is the set of odd numbers that are divisible only by 1 and themselves." Maybe am I trying too hard to be declarative.

Comment: @Frank: Try to think of "declarative" and "fits on one line" as completely different things.  Think of "good code" as another completely different thing.

Comment: @Dietrich: I'm not sure I understand your point about arity 0: a function is supposed to have always the same value for the same argument, so it could memoize (primes2 5), then use that when recursively coming up on (primes2 5) again, couldn't it?

Comment: @Frank -- It could do that.  But the compiler never does that, ever.

Comment: @Dietrich. Ok. I don't understand what exactly triggers memoization then. I thought memoization consisted in building a map between (function name, argument value) and function return value. I remember implementing simple memoization in Python that way.

Answer (score 0):

I like what Dietrich has done with the memoization, but I think theres a data structure issue here too.  Lists are just not the ideal data structure for this. They are, by necessity, lisp style cons cells with no random access.  Set seems better suited to me.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

sieve :: (Integral a) => a -> S.Set a
sieve top = let l = S.fromList (2:3:([5,11..top]++[7,13..top]))
                 iter s c
                    | cur > (div (S.findMax s) 2) = s
                    | otherwise = iter (s S.\\ (S.fromList [2*cur,3*cur..top])) (S.deleteMin c)
                    where cur = S.findMin c
             in iter l (l S.\\ (S.fromList [2,3]))
```

I know its kind of ugly, and not too declarative, but it runs rather quickly.  Im looking into a way to make this nicer looking using `Set.fold` and `Set.union` over the composites.  Any other ideas for neatening this up would be appreciated.

PS - see how `(2:3:([5,11..top]++[7,13..top]))` avoids unnecessary multiples of 3 such as the 15 in your `primes`.  Unfortunately, this ruins your ordering if you work with lists and you sign up for a sorting, but for sets thats not an issue.